# $\nabla \log \pi$ with respect to some parameters constantly being zero

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients

I am new to reinforcement learning. May I ask a simple (and maybe a bit silly) question here? I am trying to use the "one-step actor-critic" method to train a robot on a gridworld. Let's focus on the actor as there is nothing puzzling me for the critic.

I used a feedforward ANN with one hidden layer to parameterize the action preference function (i.e. the $h$ function). The ANN has one bias node in the input layer to connect to all the hidden nodes. Therefore, there are three sets of weights associated with the $h$ function -- the weights connecting the inputs to the hidden nodes (let's call it $W1$ matrix), the weights connecting the hidden nodes to the outputs (let's call it $W2$ matrix), and the weights connecting the bias node to the hidden nodes (let's call it $c$ vector).

I used the exponential soft-max as the policy function (i.e. the $\pi$ function). That is,

$$\pi(a|s,W1,W2,c) = \displaystyle\frac{e^{h(a,s,W1,W2,c)}}{\sum_be^{h(b,s,W1,W2,c)}}.$$

The inputs to the ANN are the state/feature vector, and the outputs of the ANN are the action preference values (i.e. the $h$ values). With these action preference values, the $\pi$ function can compute the probabilities for each action to be chosen.

It is easy to derive that

$$\nabla_{W1/W2/c} \log \pi(a|s,W1,W2,c) = \nabla_{W1/W2/c} h(a,s,W1,W2,c)-\sum_b \big[\nabla_{W1/W2/c}h(b,s,W1,W2,c)\pi(b|s,W1,W2,c)\big]$$

In the above, $/$ means "or".

My puzzle is, I found that $\nabla_{W2} h(\cdot,s,W1,W2,c) \equiv \sigma$, where $\sigma$ is the vector of the sigmoid activation values. That implies, $\nabla_{W2}$ is independent of actions!? Consequently, $\nabla_{W2} \log \pi(\cdot|s,W1,W2,c) \equiv 0$, which implies that $W2$ will not be updated at all...

Where did I get wrong?

(Actually, the above puzzle of mine extends to any policy gradient method as long as $\nabla \log \pi$ is involved and a feedforward ANN is used to approximate the action preferences.)